# How do I install pycrypto for Python 2.5 on Mac OS 10.6.8?

Tags: python, macos, pycrypto

To prepare my system, I followed the instructions from this [blog](http://dearauthor.com/ebooks/how-to-install-python-and-pycrypto). The salient point is

> From there, follow the defaults until you get to the “Custom Install on ‘Macintosh HD’” screen. Everything is checked but “MAC OS X 10.4 Support” and that is the program that you want to install.

Having that out of the way, I downloaded the PyCrypto tarball, and tried to install it:

```
$ curl -O http://ftp.dlitz.net/pub/dlitz/crypto/pycrypto/pycrypto-2.5.tar.gz
$ tar xvzf pycrypto-2.5.tar.gz
$ cd pycrypto-2.5
$ python2.5 setup.py install
```

After building some binaries, I get the following errors at the bottom of the dump:

```
cc1: error: unrecognized command line option "-Wno-long-double"
cc1: error: unrecognized command line option "-Wno-long-double"
lipo: can't figure out the architecture type of: /var/folders/hk/hkor0sZBGkuucGbVfeQgO++++TI/-Tmp-//ccRzz4H0.out
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

Is there anything I missed during installation?

Answer (score 0):

I just do `pip install pycrypto` or `easy_install pycrypto`.

Comment: `ld: illegal text-relocation to '___gmp_binvert_limb_table' in /usr/local/lib/libgmp.a(mp_minv_tab.o) from '___gmpn_divexact_1' in /usr/local/lib/libgmp.a(dive_1.o) for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
error: Setup script exited with error: command 'cc' failed with exit status 1` NOT WORKING

Answer (score 0):

What you need to sucessfully install pycrypto on Mac OS X:

```
ARCHFLAGS=-Wno-error=unused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future pip install pycrypto
```